# Play audio file from a certain time step in terminal?

Tags: terminal, osx, audio, sox

I need a way in which I can play an audio file in the terminal, and tell it 
from what time step it should start from?..

Example could be to start the audio file from 00:10:00... is that possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sox comes with the `play` command which takes the same arguments as `sox`. These include the `trim` effect which can specify a starting position. Effects come after the filename. So you can do, for example,

```
play myfile.mp3 trim 10:00
```